# Cortex vs Krait ARM NEON assembly

Tags: assembly, neon

We have ARM NEON assembly code working on iPhone 5. I am porting this code to SnapDragon Krait 8084 and having some problems on specific functions. One specific one is "VLD1.32". During compilation, it says this instruction isn't valid.

I've not been able to find a reliable reference for NEON instruction set on SnapDragon. Does anyone have insight to this?

Comment: The user-facing ARMv7 instruction set is identical on the processors you mentioned. The difference you're seeing is in the assembler/compiler syntax. Since the VLD instructions don't really care about the integer size since they just load 8 or 16 bytes, try removing the ".32".

Comment: Thanks BitBank. I tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Which dev tools are you using? Android? Here's how a VLD1 instruction looks in my code that compiles fine with GAS - vld1.8 {d0,d1},[r3]!

Comment: Did you enable neon with the build option?

Comment: @BitBank the .32 suffix DOES matter. It tells the CPU that the address is 32-bit aligned which is faster than unaligned access with a .8 suffix.